# Pretrained Models for Keyword-Based Text Generation

Tags: transformer, gpt, text-generation

I'm looking for an implementation that allows me to generate text based on a pre-trained model (e.g. GPT-2).

An example would be [gpt-2-keyword-generation](https://github.com/minimaxir/gpt-2-keyword-generation) ([click here for demo](https://minimaxir.com/apps/gpt2-reddit/)). As the author notes, there is

> [...] no explicit mathematical/theoetical basis behind the keywords
> aside from the typical debiasing of the text [...]

Hence my question: **Are there more sophisticated ways of keyword-based text generation** or at least any other **alternatives**?

Thank you